# Restart Computer after installing Windows Service

Tags: windows-7, windows-services, inno-setup

I created an installer using Inno Setup and I include installation of the windows service that I created. Is it necessary to restart computer after installation? even though I have already installed and started the service without problem?

Answer (score 4):

You probably already figured this out, but it's not necessary required. The registry is edited and the service is installed, so you're ready to go. The only note is that the service won't start automatically after installation so you'll have to start it manually even if the startup type has been set to Automatic. When windows reboots, the Service will start automatically.

Comment: I have checked the service in "services.msc" and its status is already started. Does this mean that the service is working properly now?

Comment: @patlimosenero: \It means that windows knows it's running. Working correctly can only be determined through observation.